# How to change the default Hub github account

Tags: git, github

I recently discovered the handy create function in hub.exe ("a wrapper for git") and I plan to mainly use it to locally create repos and then be able to upload content there.

```
hub create
```

On the first use, it asked for credentials, which I didnt think much of and I put in my non-preferred account. However now I wish to change it to my main account, but I couldn't. I tried many things to be able to change it however I cant find anything that works. Looking at the documentation said that these credentials would be stored in "~/.config/hub" as an OAuth token, but i was not able to find this file on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was incorrect. Upon rediscovering Git Bash, and entering in "~/.config/hub" i found out where it was (in %HOME%) and when I opened up the file in Notepad you could very easily see what was going on. It had a line for the username, the OAuth and the protocol. Upon destroying the data in username and OAuth, I was reprompted for details about where to login.

TLDR, to change accounts, change the hub file (probably located in "your usename"/.config